# Use `org-plus-contrib` to satisfy dependency of `org2blog`

Tags: org-mode, package

Is there a way to tell `package.el` that the `org-plus-contrib` package I already have satisfies any dependency on `org`, so that installing packages that depend on `org` (such as the afore mentioned `org2blog`) doesn't automatically install `org` as well?

This is not an actual problem: after installing `org2blog` through the Package menu I now have `org` installed in addition to `org-plus-contrib` (which includes all of `org`). This extra `org` doesn't load (when I run `M-x org-version` I can see that I get the one from `org-plus-contrib`) or bother me in any way. But since I'm not using it, I'd rather not have it.

I bet the "right way" to fix this is for the `org-plus-contrib` package to be reduced to an `org-contrib` package that depends on `org` and only contains the extra libraries, not the `org` base. But is there anything locally I can do to fix this (very minor) annoyance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have tested below to work with the in-built `package`.

Below snippet will prevent installation of packages (package symbol) listed in the let-bound `pkg-black-list` variable in the below function.

For example, after evaluating the below, doing `M-x package-install ox-asciidoc` will not install the `org` package. You will see the below in the `*Messages*` buffer:

> Package ‘org’ will not be auto-installed. See ‘modi/package-dependency-check-ignore’.

---

```el
(defun modi/package-dependency-check-ignore (orig-ret)
  "Remove the `black listed packages' from ORIG-RET.

Packages listed in the let-bound `pkg-black-list' will not be auto-installed
even if they are found as dependencies.

It is known that this advice is not effective when installed packages
asynchronously using `paradox'. Below is effective on synchronous
package installations."
  (let ((pkg-black-list '(org))
        new-ret
        pkg-name)
    (dolist (pkg-struct orig-ret)
      (setq pkg-name (package-desc-name pkg-struct))
      (if (member pkg-name pkg-black-list)
          (message (concat "Package `%s' will not be installed. "
                           "See `modi/package-dependency-check-ignore'.")
                   pkg-name)
        (push pkg-struct new-ret)))
    ;; It's *very* critical that the order of packages stays the same in NEW-RET
    ;; as in ORIG-RET. The `push' command flips the order, so use `reverse'
    ;; to flip the order back to the original.
    ;;   Without this step, you will get package activation errors when
    ;; installing packages with dependencies.
    (setq new-ret (reverse new-ret))
    new-ret))
(advice-add 'package-compute-transaction :filter-return #'modi/package-dependency-check-ignore)
```

---

*This will not work when installing packages asynchronously using the [`paradox`](https://github.com/Malabarba/paradox) package. You can still use the `paradox` package, but you would need to pick the synchronous installation option.*

Comment: This great, thanks! I'll use something just like this but making pkg-black-list a customizable variable.

Comment: I think I'll also add the possibility of using regular expressions in `pkg-black-list`.

Comment: @OmarAntolín-Camarena In that case, make the black list a string list and `(setq pkg-name (symbol-name (package-desc-name pkg-struct)))`.

Comment: Yes, that's what I did, @KaushalModi, and instead of `member` I join all the black listed strings with `"\\|"` and use `string-match-p`.

Answer (score 4):

I use `quelpa` to fake package name `org`:

```
(quelpa '(org :url "git://orgmode.org/org-mode.git" :fetcher git
            :files ("lisp/*.el" "contrib/lisp/*.el" "doc/dir" "doc/*.texi") :upgrade nil))
```

With this snippet, you will have `master` branch of git repo. ELPA version comes from `maint` branch, so you may have versions gap. Please tweak its branch with your preference.

Comment: Thanks for this answer, I didn't know about quelpa and it looks pretty interesting, but since I'm happy with the builtin package.el I'm looking for an answer geared towards it.